# Why isn't ng-repeat selecting my option when that value is already set?

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

It appears that even though I have the ng-model value set before ng-repeat creates my option, the option that corresponds to the value is not selected.

I'm i doing something wrong? or is this just the way it works. this is a real pain because I have to worry about the order I call my functions in.

This also seems odd because once I change the value to kick off a digest loop the option gets selected.

see this working example

http://jsbin.com/xufisu/6/edit

Answer (score 3):

Using `ng-repeat` on options will give you a lot of issues.  You need to use `ng-options` instead:

```
<select size="4" style="width:150px" ng-model="filterCondition.operator" 
 ng-options="operator.value as operator.displayName for operator in operators">
    <option></option> 
</select>
```

Comment: This was not the question. ng-options has it own set issues as well.

Comment: This answers the question.  Use ng-options, and "the option that corresponds to the value is not selected" is fixed.

Comment: You either use ng-options or write your own directive. Think that pretty much covers it.

Comment: Dave - what your saying is completely correct. ng-options does not have this issue I'm really trying to understand why this happens. As it would  be useful for me to deeper understanding of it. thanks for your answer anyway.